# LIB file output locations for Delphi 2009 packages

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, package, c++builder

When building a Delphi 2009 component package, how do you specify which directory should contain the resulting .hpp and .lib files needed for C++ Builder users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known bug: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=67513
This is /expected/ to be fixed in the forthcoming Update 3. (Don't worry about the 10.0 resolved in build number, that is a mistake that will be corrected when Update 3 is released and all the bug fixes get synchronized back to QC)

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Answer (score 4):

On the Project|Options|Delphi Compiler|Linking page, the first two items are C++Builder .hpp output directory and C++Buidler .obj output directory should do what you want. The .lib and .bpi files. However, it seems that there is a bit of a bug in how these options are passed to the compiler... I'll speak with the engineer responsible about it.

From the command-line DCC32 you can use the following to control where to place these items:

```
-N0<path> = unit .dcu output directory
-NH<path> = unit .hpp output directory
-NO<path> = unit .obj output directory
-NB<path> = unit .bpi output directory
```

Note that the -NB switch AFAICR, also controls where the .lib file goes as well.

Comment: Allen - welcome to SO - good to see you here!
However, I don't see either of those options. The first two I see are "Debug Information" and "Image Base"....??

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't. None of the directory options seem to control it. However, you could probably define a post-build event (Project->Options->Build events) which would copy the files to where you wanted them.